# MSMQ enabling error

Tags: windows, msmq

I am having problems with enabling MSMQ.

**My specific error is**

> The Message Queuing service will not join the ...domain. 
>       An MSMQ Configuration (msmq) object exists in the new domain with an ID differing from the service ID. 
>       Please delete the MSMQ Configuration object in the new domain, restart the Message Queuing service, and log on again.

Did anyone face with this problem before? I tried to apply many solutions, but could not figure out what is causing this exactly. I lost more than a day and still there is no solution worked for me.

tried to apply this solution but did not work
[Event ID 2164 — Message Queuing Functioning in Domain Mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773660%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

I tried this 
Open Registry Editor. To open Registry Editor, click Start. In the search box type regedit, and then press ENTER.
In Registry Editor, expand HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, expand SOFTWARE, expand Microsoft, expand MSMQ, and then click Setup.
In the console tree, double-click msmq_ADIntegrated.
Confirm that Value data is set to 1.
Under MSMQ, expand Parameters.
In the details pane, double-click Workgroup.
Verify that Value data is not set to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out.

The problem is, I removed the default website from IIS, I brought it back then I could enable MSMQ